# Question about VideoPlayer's skin VideoPlayerSkin

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

When I add a VideoPlayer control to my flex project, I didn't assign a skinclass to it. So, how does flashbuilder apply the VideoPlayerSkin.mxml to VideoPlayer?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, inside your skin class, VideoPlayerSkin.mxml, you need the following:

```
<fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("components.VideoPlayer")]</fx:Metadata>
```